# How to ignore list elements when extracting with pattern matching

Tags: assignment

If I have a simple list, say {1, 2, 3}, and I want to extract a subset of the elements, what is the correct syntax? e.g.

```
{ i, _, j } = {1, 2, 3}
```

I want i = 1 & j = 3 (which works), but I get the following warning:

```
Set::nosym: _ does not contain a symbol to attach a rule to.
```

so clearly I am using the wrong placeholder for elements I wish to ignore.

Comment: The warning appears because you are trying to assign `2` to `_`. There are a lot of ways to do what you need: `{i, j} = Drop[{1,2,3}, {2}]` for example.

Comment: It should be noted that often this type of situation is easily avoidable by instead doing something like: `{i,j}={1,2,3}[[{1, 3}]]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Turn off the warning

It should be noted that we can treat `Set::nosym` as a *warning* message rather than an error, and simply turn it [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html):

```
Off[Set::nosym]

{i, _, j} = {1, 2, 3};

{i, j}
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

#### throw-away Symbol

You could asko designate a Symbol for this purpose as a kind of dev/null, using e.g. `$Post` to clear it every time.  I'll pick `\[DoubleDagger]`, entered <kbd>Esc</kbd>`ddg`<kbd>Esc</kbd> and displayed as `‡`:

```
$Post = ((‡ =.; #) &);
```

Now you could make your assignment:

```
{i, ‡, j} = {1, 2, 3};
```

The value of `‡` is cleared after each evaluation so as not to take up memory.

---

For reference, the definition of `$Post` above is not entirely neutral.  For example, by default entering `Sequence @@ {1, 2, 3}` will return `Sequence[1, 2, 3]` whereas with the definition it will return `1`.  The ugly but proper definition would be something like:

```
$Post = Function[x, ‡ =.; Unevaluated@x, HoldAllComplete];
```

Since `$Post` is only one way to clear the Symbol I didn't want to clutter the top of the answer with this code.  Other methods would be [`RunScheduledTask`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RunScheduledTask.html), [`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEpilog.html), etc.

Comment: I just got a new favorite dummy symbol! And very interesting answer too!

Comment: @Pinguin Thanks.  I think [Esc] :-@ [Esc] is a nice option. :^)

Comment: good thing they "announced" retina support for the Mac, that'll look great in the code

Answer (score 1):

The equal sign is trying to assign the list `{1,2,3}` to the left hand side `{i,_,j}` and you cannot assign 2 to `_`.

Try the following code:

```
list = {a, b, c};
Extract[list, {{1}, {3}}]
{First[list], Last[list]}
Replace[list, {i_, _, j_} :> {i, j}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the more verbose syntax for Extract which will certainly work, but I was hoping there was a more natural, concise syntax similar to that which I suggested?