# Is there a convention on which name to use for a throwaway variable? (Like underscore in Python)

Tags: assignment, variable, coding-style

I would prefer to write `{_, foo} = LongFunctionName[arg1, arg2]` instead of `foo = LongFunctionName[arg1, arg2][[2]]` or `foo = Last @ LongFunctionName[arg1, arg2]`. Using an actual name for the throwaway variable makes code unnecessarily verbose and can be misleading/confusing. Is it a good idea to use `$` for throwaways?

Comment: I don't believe there is a convention.  In fact I don't believe this is a common method at all, in *Mathematica*.  This is closely related to [(30138)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30138/121) which is probably the one @Kuba was thinking of.

Comment: +1, I would like to see a "throwaway variable" in Mathematica. MATLAB also has it, it uses the tilde.

Comment: @ZeitPolizei I would like to know if you would object to my closing this question as a duplicate of the one linked above.  I feel that this is probably best addressed in a single place, and if there are aspects of your question that are not addressed there it may be better to extend that question rather than creating a separate one.  If this action is taken your question will remain as an entry point for searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you *can* write `{_, foo} = . . .` and it works, as noted in [How to ignore list elements when extracting with pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30138/121).

If one is going to make use of this it may be desirable to turn [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html) [`Set::nosym`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/nosym.html).

```
Off[Set::nosym]

{a, _, b} = {1, 2, 3};

{a, b}
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

Perhaps this is as close to a convention as we can find?

Comment: Provided that `LongFunctionName[...]` immediately evaluates to a list of matching length, which it probably should for an undelayed assignment.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes, that is an unstated assumption, since e.g. `{a, b} := foo[x]` doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose LLIAMnYP meant `{a,b} = {1,2,3}` case.

Comment: @Kuba well, that would be a similar problem.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Ok, I just wasn't sure if there is a misunderstanding or not :)

Answer (score 4):

This one should not need to suppress messages:

```
Block[{a}, {a, b, a} = {1, 2, 3}];
a
b
(* a *) 
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: While `Block` is faster I'd probably go with `Module` because of reasons: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25934/5478